# Efficient Way of Filtering Array and Mapping in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to get array that have `status` of "Existing" only and don't add the status in the newArray. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

```
const products = [
    {
        "id": "111",
        "name": "grapes",
        "status": "Linked",
    },
    {
        "id": "222",
        "name": "banana",
        "status": "Existing",
    },
    {
        "id": "333",
        "name": "mango",
        "status": "Existing",
    },
    {
      "id": "444",
      "name": "salad",
      "status": "Linked",
      
    },
    {
        "id": "555",
        "name": "juice",
        "status": "Existing",
    }
]

  const newArray = 
    products?.map(({ name = '', id = '' }) => ({
      name,
      id,
    }))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2722159/90527)

Comment: @outis. I wanted to filter it first then map it probably? their using old style of JS.

Comment: The most efficient way in number of lines of code? Or the most efficient way in performance?

Comment: @Joseph: if your question is "how to filter and then remove properties from results?", it's two questions, one of which is covered by the previously linked question, one by "[How to keep a few properties in each returned object from a fetch call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/68625151/90527)". If one of your questions is along the lines of "how to have an anonymous function without a return?" or "what's the shortest syntax for anonymous functions?", it's a duplicate of "[Is there a C#-like lambda syntax in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7190439/90527)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to do both in one array function. I would filter it by `status === "Existing"` using `filter`, then `map` it, removing the `status` property.

```js
const products = [{
    "id": "111",
    "name": "grapes",
    "status": "Linked",
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "name": "banana",
    "status": "Existing",
  },
  {
    "id": "333",
    "name": "mango",
    "status": "Existing",
  },
  {
    "id": "444",
    "name": "salad",
    "status": "Linked",

  },
  {
    "id": "555",
    "name": "juice",
    "status": "Existing",
  }
]

const newArray = products.filter((elem) => elem.status === "Existing")
     .map(({ id, name, status }) => ({ id, name }))

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thank you. can you use es6 and above like don't use `return` anymore

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the keyword `return` from the array functions.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient in terms of lines of code is probably just a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) followed by a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation:

```
const result = products.filter(({status}) => status === 'Existing')
                       .map(({id, name}) => ({id, name}));
```

---

**Full snippet:**

```js
const products = [{
  "id": "111",
  "name": "grapes",
  "status": "Linked",
}, {
  "id": "222",
  "name": "banana",
  "status": "Existing",
}, {
  "id": "333",
  "name": "mango",
  "status": "Existing",
}, {
  "id": "444",
  "name": "salad",
  "status": "Linked",

}, {
  "id": "555",
  "name": "juice",
  "status": "Existing",
}];

const result = products.filter(({status}) => status === 'Existing')
                       .map(({id, name}) => ({id, name}));
                       
console.log(result);
```

Since that requires a double iteration, the most efficient in terms of performance will probably be an explicit `for` loop that pushes matching values into a result array.

If you want to do everything in a single iteration but still maintain a functional approach, you could do everything with one [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation:

```js
const products = [{
  "id": "111",
  "name": "grapes",
  "status": "Linked",
}, {
  "id": "222",
  "name": "banana",
  "status": "Existing",
}, {
  "id": "333",
  "name": "mango",
  "status": "Existing",
}, {
  "id": "444",
  "name": "salad",
  "status": "Linked",

}, {
  "id": "555",
  "name": "juice",
  "status": "Existing",
}];

const result = products.reduce((a, {id, name, status}) => {
  if (status === 'Existing') a.push({id, name});
  return a;
}, []);
                       
console.log(result);
```

Comment: In the very first bit of code you added, you forgot to enclose return object in`{}` in `(id, name)`